# How to install a Specific Version of Node on Ubuntu Server

Tags: 16.04, server, lubuntu, amazon-ec2, nodejs

I am trying to install `Node 6.11.3` on my Ubuntu Server.
I don't want to use nvm for this.

I have already used this link but it just does not work out while using jenkins and stuff.

I want to specifically install NodeJS 6.11.3. How do I do that? Please help.

I tried this `sudo apt-get install nodejs=6.11.3` but nothing happens.

**Steps for NVM which I don't want to use**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html

Please bear with me. This is my first attempt on anything on server and also on askUbuntu.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Install nodejs 6**

Get your nodejs tarball from node site e.g. `node-v6.11.3-linux-x64.tar.gz` from [v6.11.3](https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.11.3/)

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.11.3/node-v6.11.3-linux-x64.tar.g‌​z
```

Unpack provided archive files to `/opt/nodejs`

```
mkdir -p /opt/nodejs
tar -xvzf node-v6.11.3-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/nodejs/
```

**Create link to current node version**

```
cd /opt/nodejs
mv node-v6.11.3-linux-x64 6.11.3
ln -s 6.11.3 current
```

**Create link to current node binary**

```
ln -s /opt/nodejs/current/bin/node /bin/node
```

**Verify Node version**

```
node -v
v6.11.3
```

Comment: i might be really stupid asking this , but just on the base directly when we login i need to run this commands in sequence i have no idea on servers and installation my first hands on please help

Comment: Also this file is downloaded locally how to get it up to the server ? i am noob so please dnt laugh

Comment: I am running this command `tar -xvzf node-v6.11.3-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /home/rahul/Downloads/
` gives me error

Comment: 1-Do you have ssh access to your server ? 2- You can move the tarball to the server with scp or use wget to download it directly if you have internet connexion `wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.11.3/node-v6.11.3-linux-x64.tar.gz` 3- What's the error message you get after tar?

Comment: I have ssh access to the server and a active internet connection, says no such file or directry

Comment: when i run the mv node command i get this error `mv: cannot stat 'node-v6.11.3-linux-x64': No such file or directory
`

Comment: any idea @strom

Comment: you need to go where `node-v6.11.3-linux-x64` is , just cd to the path you gave to tar -C

Comment: node is installed but the third step thows error for me `sudo ln -s /opt/nodejs/current/bin/node /bin/node
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/bin/node': File exists`

Comment: I am up voting it but why the third step did not work ?

Comment: no it is a new box no node verison installed just the command didnot work . But while checking node -v shows 6.11.3  without that step will it fail. Or is it fine?

Comment: great . Hope u r right

Comment: incredible answer .. actually saved my day.. it allows me to easily switch  between node / npm versions ( although with a little nix difficulty ) easily

Answer (score 3):

Node.js is available as a snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. Specific to Node.js, developers can choose from one or more of the currently supported releases and get regular automatic updates directly from NodeSource. Node.js versions 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 and 18 are currently available, with the Snap Store being updated within hours or minutes of a Node.js release.

Node can be installed with a single command, for example:

```
sudo snap install node --classic --channel 11/stable
```

The node snap can be accessed by the command `node`, for example:

```
$ node -v  
v11.5.0
```

An up-to-date version of npm will installed as part of the node snap. npm should be run outside of the node repl, in your normal shell. After installing the node snap run the following command to enable npm update checking:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /home/your-username/.config
```

Replace  **`your-username`** in the above command with your own username. Then run `npm -v` to check if the version of npm is up-to-date. As an example I checked that npm was up-to-date, checked the version of an already installed package named yarn with the command `npm list yarn` and then updated the existing yarn package to the latest version with the command `npm update yarn`

Users can switch between versions of Node.js at any time without needing to involve additional tools like nvm (Node Version Manager), for example:

```
sudo snap refresh node --channel=10/stable
```

Users can test bleeding-edge versions of Node.js that can be installed from the latest edge channel by switching with:

```
sudo snap switch node --edge
```

This approach is only recommended for those users who are willing to participate in testing and bug reporting upstream.

#### Node.js LTS schedule

| Release | Status | Codename | Initial release | LTS Start | Maintenance Start | Maintenance End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6.x | EOL | Boron | 2016-04-26 | 2016-10-18 | 2018-04-30 | 2019-04-30 |
| 7.x | EOL |  | 2017-05-30 |  |  | 2017-06-30 |
| 8.x | EOL | Carbon | 2016-10-25 | 2017-10-31 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-12-31 |
| 9.x | EOL |  | 2017-10-01 |  |  | 2018-06-30 |
| 10.x | EOL | Dubnium | 2018-04-24 | 2018-10-30 | 2020-05-19 | 2021-04-30 |
| 11.x | EOL |  | 2018-10-23 |  |  | 2019-06-01 |
| 12.x | Maintenance LTS | Erbium | 2019-04-23 | 2019-10-21 | 2020-11-301 | 2022-04-30 |
| 13.x | EOL |  | 2019-10-22 |  |  | 2020-06-01 |
| 14.x | Maintenance LTS | Fermium | 2020-04-21 | 2020-10-27 | 2021-10-30 | 2023-04-30 |
| 16.x | Active LTS | Gallium | 2021-04-20 | 2021-10-26 | 2022-10-18 | 2024-04-30 |
| 17.x | Current |  | 2021-10-19 |  | 2022-04-01 | 2022-06-01 |
| 18.x | Current |  | 2022-04-19 | 2022-10-25 | 2023-10-18 | 2025-04-30 |

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs provides an official wiki for the Installation process, that wiki is recently updated on 10-Nov-2018. @storm 's answer was useful when there was no document available.

https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation

This link is more about `installing Node.js via binary archive on Linux`

**You can download the binary archive from here.**

https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks, @KevinBowen will update more information along with a link to justify my response as separate answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `n` for node's version managements

```
$ npm install -g n
$ n 6.11.3
```

Then you can check the version

```
$ node -v
$ v6.11.3
```